# What should be done to handle Imbalanced classes in case of Multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

I have a dataset which consist of user tickets which is random in pattern and some 56 cols in it and it is a text data. My task is to create a model and train it to identify and predict to which category the tickets belongs to, and we have 100 + category being there. The count for suppose category A is 70,000 other is 50,0000 and for some category the ticket count goes down to 1 is this an imbalanced data? If is is how should i handle this for multi class classification and for till now to handle this data which i think is is imbalanced i am using SMOTE but the accuracy decreases. What should i do in this case?

I have already tried DecisionTree classifier and now working on Logisitic regression.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use F1-score as the evaluation metric in such cases(highly imbalanced data).

2) Use stratified sampling while train_test split.

3) Try one vs rest classifier.

4) Use algorithms like xgboost, lightgbm and catboost.